# javascript - how to get the last loop iteration if data length is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop in JavaScript:

`data` is just a list of strings. I don't know its length, because data is coming dynamically. This is my loop:

```
for (var i=1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //how do i catch the last string in the list in loop?
};
```

it is important that i catch the last object inside loop

is there any `this.last()` thing which gives me the last iteration?

Comment: if you only want the last one and don't need the array after that, a simple data.pop() will remove the last one and give it to you. data.slice(-1)[0] will give you the last one without mutating the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the last element there is no need to iterate the entire loop.

```
var last = data[data.length - 1];
```

Comment: @doniyor We all have our moments!

Answer (score 3):

To simply capture the last element in an array, use:

```
var lastItem = data[data.length - 1];
```

Or to create a new array containing only the last element, use this:

```
var lastItem = data.slice(-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check `if data[i+1] == undefined` inside the loop to find out when you are in the last loop iteration.

When you have no real reason to loop through the array, you can use `data[data.length - 1]` to access the last entry of the array.